# tslint configuration issue in gulp project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, tslint, gulp-watch

I run, gulp bundle and I'm getting this error so any body know why it might be?

gulp --version
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

node --version
v12.18.3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the package

`npm i @microsoft/sp-tslint-rules`

Comment: hi @Tiko now i'm getting this error instead  "Error - [tslint] no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead. "

Comment: If it's in your json file, just remove it

Comment: oh ok. Thank it work now. another quick question, I'm seeing this error " [18:27:40] Task never defined: build-solution " when I do gulp build-solution --ship so it's an error that I need to be concern or not really?.